# How can I read separate numbers/lines from a .txt and input them to 2 different arrays

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program that reads lines from a .txt and inputs them to 2 different arrays.

So far I have this:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main() {
        FILE * ifp = fopen("input.txt","r"); 
        FILE * ofp = fopen ("output.txt", "w"); 
        int participants = 0, i;  
        char name [10];
        float grade [10];
        float perc [10];

        fscanf(ifp, "%d", &participants);

        for (i=1; i<participants; i++) {
             fscanf(ifp, "%s", &name);

             fscanf(ifp, "%f", &grade);

        }

        printf( "%d\n", participants);
        printf( "%s\n", name);
        printf( "%f\n", grade);

        fclose(ifp);
        fclose(ofp);

        return 0;
    }
```

The txt I'm trying to read is:

```
    2 
    Optimus 
    45 90 
    30 60 
    25 30 
    50 70 
    Megatron 
    5 6 
    7 9 
    3 4 
    8 10
```

My problem is that it picks up the first 2 lines but stops when it gets to the numbers. I'm trying to get the names into an array and all the numbers, in pairs in a different array. Right now I'm just trying to check to see if I am picking up the numbers in the array but its not picking them all up.

This is the output that I get:

```
    2
    Optimus
    0.000000
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

This is my new code after some changes:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main() {
        FILE * ifp = fopen("input.txt","r");
        FILE * ofp = fopen ("output.txt", "w");
        int participants = 0, i , j; 
       char name [10];
        int grade [26];
        float perc [26];

        fscanf(ifp, "%d", &participants);

        for (i=1; i<participants; i++) {
             fscanf(ifp, " %s", name);
             fscanf(ifp, " %d", grade);

        }

        printf( "%d\n", participants);
        printf( "%s\n", name);
        printf( "%d\n", grade[0]);

        fclose(ifp);
        fclose(ofp);

      return 0;
    }
```

And my new output is :

```
    2
    Optimus
    45
```

**EDIT 2**

What I need to do with those numbers later is divide the first number in a line with the second number in that same line, multiply it by 10, and then have it display "*" according to the number. So it would print out like this:

```
    Optimus
    +:  *****
    -:  *****
    *:  ********
    /:  *******
    Megatron
    +:  ********
    -:  *******
    *:  *******
    /:  ********
```

"+" is the first line under a name.
"-" is the second line under that same name. 
"*" for the third.
"/" for the fourth.

Answer (score 1):

This is your main problem:

```
    printf( "%f\n", grade);
```

You're trying to print a pointer as a float. You want `grade[0]`.

In this line:

```
    fscanf(ifp, "%f", &grade);
```

This will work, but it's not correct. It should be `&grade[0]` or just plain `grade`.

Of course in your final version, you'll need to adjust the array subscripts. You'll also need to allocate more arrays for the name - you currently can only store one.

To read in the data you will need to change the program a lot. You could declare `grade` as `grade[10][8]` (assuming a maximum of 10 participants), and store each of the 8 integers in the array. A loop like this would process it:

```
   for (i = 0; i < participants; i++) {
      fscanf(ifp, "%s", name);             // read the name (you need to fix this)
      for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        fscanf(ifp, "%d", &grade[i][j]);   // store each number
      }
   }
```

Comment: fscanf(ifp, "%f", &grade); is technically correct as well. As &grade == grade.

Comment: @Armin, it's not. &grade is a pointer to an array, _not_ to an element.

Comment: Go try it and check the addresses of &grade and grade, it is the same.

Comment: Ok, so I changed it and now it picks up the first number but stops there. How can I make it so that it continues to pick up the other numbers and when it gets to the name, it adds that to the "name" array.

Comment: @Armin, I'm quite aware of that, but they're not the same type.

Comment: @Drieke - you'll need something a bit more complicated to read the text file. As it stands you read a number, then a word, then you start a loop that isn't going to help. Are there always a sequence of 4 pairs of digits after the word? If so, that makes it a lot easier.

Comment: @Drieke, I've given you a suggestion to help, but this is really for answering specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

`name` and `grade` are arrays - the address of the variable is implicit for an array. So the address operator should not be used for these variables.

```
fscanf(ifp, "%s", name);
fscanf(ifp, "%f", grade);
```